# how to make rule handling tokens and returning the token

Tags: java, nlp, gate

I am trying to make a rule to detect a pattern saying  of . where x is a word annotated under "Service" annotation(i already enterd its list in gazeetter) and y can be any token and i want my rule to return the value of y.

I successfully made the rule for y(where token length=1). Now i want to extend it for y whose length>1.

This runs fine:

```
rule: of
(
{Service}
{Token.string=="of"}
({Token}):tok

):ser
-->
tok.Of={queryparam=:tok.Token@string}
```

and i use this queryparam using this jape in my java programme.

But now i want is to return multiple tokens after of and use it in my java program.
I tried using various patterns but they are not working. I tried using inputAS and outputAS on rhs but having hard time to run it successfully.
Appreciable if any1 can help me.

Comment: Can you give 5-6 examples of Gazetteer entries you marked as 'Service'? This would help to understand your goal better. An example of 'multiple tokens' you expect after 'Service' would help too.

Comment: sure sir..i hav added several lists of weather,library etc that contains words like temperature,price, artistName, author,pressure, genre and many more. So what i want is if "temperature of Washington Dc" is passed then the rule should set a string =Washington Dc.